# Prestashop module: Products from category on product page

Tags: php, module, prestashop, categories, product

I have to ask how to get other products from the same category as actual product on product page. 
I have plan how to do it, but i can't find proper functions(everything should be done in module.php file for sure):

1. Get parent category for product
2. Get products for that category (as array)
3. Display products in .tpl.

And only thing i can do is third point of my "plan", becouse lack of skill/knowledge.

If you can tell me which functions i should use i would be gratefull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. It was easier than i thought. I did it in .tpl.

```
{foreach from=$products item=product}
{if $product.id_category_default ===$category->id_category}
<a href="{$link->getProductLink({$product.id_product})}">Link</a>
{/if}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 0):

To work with all languages:

Change 
getProductLink({$product.id_product})}">Link

With

getProductLink({$product.id_product})}">{l s='Link' }